# How to conditionally print the input by user in Python?

Tags: python

```
def ask_question(question, option1, option2, option3, option4):
    print(question)
    print('1', option1)
    print('2', option2)
    print('3', option3)
    print('4', option4)
    print('Your answer:', input())

ask_question('Which color is your favorite?', 'red',
'lime', 'blue', 'gray')
```

What should I add more to fulfill
"if a choice is equal to the empty string,
then do not print that choice nor the adjacent number to the screen" this condition?

Comment: Get the input before you call print. Test the returned value from input(). Also, IMHO, calling input() as a parameter is very bad style

Answer (score 0):

You should better try something like this:

```
var = input()
print(f"Your answer: {var}") if var else print('')
```

This is an inline `if` statement, that prints a newline if the `input`'s returned value is `False`: `''`.

---

If you want to avoid all the options which are empty strings:

```
def ask(question, *options):
    print(question)
    for index, option in enumerate(options):
        if option:
            print(f"{index} {option}")
```

Comment: "but input was called after print" That's not the case. Arguments are completely evaluated before being passed to a function – ``input()`` is evaluated first, as ``print`` cannot be called otherwise.

Comment: Oh. Now i notice you are right, didn't know this (even if it's obvious). Thanks

Comment: I've edited the question, now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to skip print that option if it is an empty string. then one of the solutions is this, (can be improvised based on the more specific requirements).

```
def ask_question(question, option1, option2, option3, option4):
    print(question)
    print('1', option1) if option1 != '' else None #or do what you want
    print('2', option2) if option2 != '' else None 
    print('3', option3) if option3 != '' else None 
    print('4', option4) if option4 != '' else None 
    print('Your answer:', input())
    

ask_question('Which color is your favorite?', 'red',
'lime', 'blue', 'gray')
```